# Blocks missing after clearing the cache or visiting the page that is not cached yet

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm not sure whats wrong with my implementation. I need to print a region in node tpl so I created this code in

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($plugin = context_get_plugin('reaction', 'block')) {
    if (isset($plugin)) {
      $variables['rail_full'] = $plugin->block_get_blocks_by_region('rail_full');
    }
  }
}
```

And in my node tpl

```
<?php print render($rail_full); ?>
```

The problem is every clear cache I made all the blocks are missing (homepage and inner pages) in first page load or visiting a page that is not cached yet.

Any idea what I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry my bad I should wrap the above code to a condition if `"view_mode = teaser"`

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    if ($plugin = context_get_plugin('reaction', 'block')) {
      if (isset($plugin)) {
        $variables['rail_full'] = $plugin->block_get_blocks_by_region('rail_full');
      }
    }
  } else {
   // Do anything here when teaser
  }
}
```